# Assigning a user a different layout via mysql

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm working on a website that has an edit profile details page. One of the options I have set to edit is the layout. I am trying to control the display of the layout with cookies and mysql queries. Currently I am using if and else statments after the user input is passed via form submission to decide which cookie to set for the layout.

Then, on the actual view profile page that displays the profile, I am using if else statments again with mysql queries (along with a GET variable that is set to the usersname) to decide which layout is called for that user.

> Heres the problem. I am having a problem finding the correct way to
>   display the layout (with a sql query) that was chosen for the user
>   that was called with the GET variable.

My users table is laid out with the row names:

id (auto incre)
username
name
age
gender
aboutme
likes
dislikes
music
template_id

and my templates table is set out with the row names:

template_id (auto incre)
Head_Open
Head_Close
Page_End
Date

I thought about some type of join on both tables, but I can't seem to figure it out. I need it so each user is also added multiple times in the templates table or maybe just updated in the templates table for each unique layout in the table.

If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: I think these "row names" are actually column names.

Comment: What you want ? which layout currently associated with user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying for

`"select tpl.* from users u inner join templates tpl on tpl.template_id = u.template_id where u.name = " + $THE_USER_NAME`

should return the template(s). I am assuming you do know how to get THE_USER_NAME and how to extract the information from the rows returned.

Comment: Thank you. Before I checked this thread I just tried: SELECT * FROM userprofile, template "." WHERE userprofile.template_id = 
template.template_id AND userprofile.username ='$u'                  and it seemed to have worked. And yes, I know how to get the username and how to extract the info. ;P

Comment: That exactly it, except for the field names you provided. But I prefer the `inner join` syntax to make it clear what is your intention and it gets a lot more readable when dealing with many tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do join of two tables as below to get current layout of your logged in user.

```
$query = "select t.* from users u, templates t where u.template_id = t.template_id AND u.id = '".$_GET['userid']."'";
```